# batch file for curl

Tags: xml, batch-file, curl

I would like to create a windows batch file for a curl command that will run every five minutes and save it to a local file. Here's my curl command

```
curl -k https://root:password@rbc-v1-ml/webacs/api/v1data/ClientDetails?.full=true > C:\Users\Desktop\Sample1\curl
```

May I ask how can I do a batch file?

Comment: You do it exactly like that, what isn't working?

Comment: No details was shown in the xml file.

Comment: The type of file it will produce is XML file in C:\Users\Desktop\Sample1\curl but the file produced has no content

Answer (score 0):

Something like this: ?

```
@echo off
echo Begining at %time%
set file=https://root:password@rbc-v1-ml/webacs/api/v1data/ClientDetails?.full=true
if not exist "C:\Users\Desktop\Sample1\curl" echo. > "C:\Users\Desktop\Sample1\curl"
:top
echo Ran at %time%
curl -k %file% >> C:\Users\Desktop\Sample1\curl
echo waiting 5 minutes... Press Q to download now.
choice /c q /d q /t 300 /n
goto top
```

Note: You may need to change the URL from

```
https://root:password@rbc-v1-ml/webacs/api/v1data/ClientDetails?.full=true
```

to

```
https://root:password@rbc-v1-ml/webacs/api/v1data/ClientDetails?.full^=true
```

I'm not quite sure how it will handle it.